# Jumping animation with landing and jumping sprites

Tags: game-development, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I have 3 sprites that I want to make a jumping animation with:

```
spr_conejo_idle - 2 frames
spr_conejo_airbourne_up - 5 frames (4 for the jump and the last one frozen while vsp < 0)
spr_conejo_airbourne_down - 4 frames (1 for when vsp > 0 and the last 3 for the landing)
```

I'm trying to make it so that when the object jumps (`vsp > 0`), set the `spr_conejo_airbourne_up` sprite and keep the last frame frozen until it starts falling (`vsp =< 0`). when it starts falling, the sprite should be `spr_conejo_airbourne_down` which I want to freeze on the first frame until it vertically collides with a wall object, which will unfreeze the sprite, showing the landing animation, and finally the idle one.

What I tried:

**CREATE EVENT**

```
hp = 1;
hsp = 0;
vsp = 0;
grv = 0.3;
maxIdle = 360;
onFloor = true;
hitfrom = 0;
size = 1;
```

**STEP EVENT**

```
vsp += grv;

//time until next jump
maxIdle--;


if (place_meeting(x,y+1,obj_wall)){
    onFloor = true;
}
else {
    onFloor = false;
}

//if obj is on floor and time until next jump =< 0, jump
if (onFloor){
    if (maxIdle <= 0){
        maxIdle = random_range(60, 360);
        vsp = -6;
        onFloor = false;
        hsp = random_range(-3,3);
    }
}

//if jumping
if(!onFloor){
    // if going upwards
    if (sign(vsp) < 0) {
        //show jumping animation (will freeze on the Animation End event)
        image_speed = 1;
        sprite_index = spr_conejo_airbourne_up;
    }
    // if falling
    else {
        //freeze frame until on ground
        image_speed = 0;
        sprite_index = spr_conejo_airbourne_down;
    }
}
//if on ground
else{
    //continue animation (should trigger animation end event if sprite is airboune down, and change to idle)
    image_speed = 1;
    vsp = 0;
    hsp = 0;
}

//horizontal collision
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,obj_wall)){
    while (!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp),y,obj_wall)){
        x += sign(hsp);
    }
    hsp = 0;
}

x += hsp;

//vertical collision
if (place_meeting(x,y+vsp,obj_wall)){
    while (!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),obj_wall)){
        y += sign(vsp);
    }
    vsp = 0;
}

y += vsp;

if (hsp != 0) image_xscale = sign(hsp)*-1;
```

**ANIMATION END EVENT**

```
//freeze last frame of jumping animation
if (sprite_index == spr_conejo_airbourne_up) image_speed = 0;
//when landing animation finishes, change to idle
if (sprite_index == spr_conejo_airbourne_down) sprite_index = spr_conejo_idle;
```

**WHAT's WRONG**
When the object is on the floor, the sprite doesn't change to `spr_conejo_idle`. It constantly loops on `spr_conejo_airbourne_down`.
Sometimes while mid air, sprite changes to `spr_idle` for a few frames.

[GIF of behaviour and sprite strips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmotI.jpg)

Comment: We have a description of what you want .. And the code of what you tried, but we have no more information than that to go on.  What is the output?  Where is the problem?  Are there any errors?  Please do your best to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Zak I added the sprite strips, a gif of the behavior, and some wrong things I noticed testing. I hope that's enough to reproduce my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did you give your object a collision mask? I gave it a simple rectangular mask (based on the "idle") sprite and the landing animation seems to trigger as expected.
2. There are two halves to this:

   1. You do not rewind image index when changing to `airborne_down`. I changed

      ```js
      sprite_index = spr_conejo_airbourne_down;
      ```

      to

      ```js
      if (sprite_index != spr_conejo_airbourne_down) {
          image_index = 0;
          sprite_index = spr_conejo_airbourne_down;
      }
      ```
   2. You're not freezing the *last* frame of airborne_up, you're freezing whichever frame it was during Animation End, which is usually the *first* frame (since the animation just ended and restarted). I changed

      ```js
      if (sprite_index == spr_conejo_airbourne_up) image_speed = 0;
      ```

      to

      ```js
      if (sprite_index == spr_conejo_airbourne_up) {
          image_speed = 0;
          image_index = image_number - 1;
      }
      ```

With all that done, the rabbits<sup>(?)</sup> seem to be going about their business pretty normally.

[Test project YYZ](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vmjh4b86bcds3x/bun.yyz?dl=0)

[image]